# URL regexp validation: deny if there isn't 3 W's in URL

Tags: php, regex, validation, url

I have this regular expression to validate the URL: `^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/\S*)?$^`. This regular expression works smoothly but I want to add a limit the amount of W's in the beginning of the URL.

If the user tries to save the URL with under 3 W's (for example ww), the regular expression will deny the save. The same result will also happens if the user tries to save the URL with more than 3 W's (for example wwww).

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: from your question it seems like your users can bookmark urls. however there are a lot of websites which advertise their url without www. and also work perfectly fine. (technically it is more work to have those three w ;). you may want to reconsider this rule into something like 'if the suburl consists only of w's and there is less or more than 3'. also in this case you will have false positives since it is perfectly valid to have a site like ww.example.com or w2.example.com.

Comment: Do you just want to check whether it starts with `www.` (i.e. regexp `^www\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/\S*)?$^`) or something else?

Comment: My mistake - regular expressions does not deny or allow validation, it matches. I want to see if the URL contains "www" and if it does, check if this string is exactly 3 W's, not one or two or four or more.

Comment: @Erik see my update in answer. This pattern whether it starts with exactly www. So it matches www.google.co, google.com but not ww.google.com.

Comment: in regex *contains www* and *starts with www* are not same.

Comment: Thanks but I must say that your regular expression have the same result as GGG's :/ See my latest comment for his answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sort of filtering is not a good fit for regular expressions, I think.

The problem is that the rules for what should be a "match" are actually pretty complicated. Essentially the rules are this:

Match something if it has :

- start of text
- either:

  - exactly three `w` characters followed by a dot **OR**
  - any alphanumeric characters or dots repeated any number of times, followed by a dot

    - *unless all of those characters are `w` characters, but the number of characters is not equal to three (plus the dot)*
- two or three more alphanumeric characters
- end of text

The *unless all of those characters are w characters...* part is the tricky part. Regex isn't really well suited to this task.

---

For "historical" purposes:

Use `{n}` to repeat part of the expression *n* times.

```
^w{3}\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?$
```

Use `?` to make part of the expression optional.

The parentheses are a grouping operator. The "w times three" and dot are moved inside the group, and the group is made optional with the `?` operator.

```
^Guess what? this doesn't work.$
^I tried to delete the answer but I can't until you unaccept it.$
```

I also escaped the last forward slash with a backslash in these examples, since regular expressions are often delimited with `/` characters. You can remove it if you don't need it.

Comment: Thank you! But I also want to match without the www.

Comment: Thanks but according to regexpal.com it doesn't match any URL's without www. :/

Comment: yeah i forgot the `?` :p Check it again

Comment: Hm. It seems to match any length of www :/

Comment: I think its better to do it with explode.

Comment: Yeah, this isn't going to work with regex. I tried to delete the answer but it won't let me. I don't think this will even work with negative lookbehinds.

Answer (score 0):

This regex will apply to all test cases

```
 "^(https?:\\/\\/)?www{1}\." +
 "((([a-z\\d]([a-z\\d-]*[a-z\\d])*)\\.)+[a-z]{2,}|" + 
 "((\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}))" + 
 "(\\:\\d+)?(\\/[-a-z\\d%_.~+]*)*"`enter code here`
```